# Progress bars to indicate user count & competition end date for mobile

Tags: mobile, android, ios, progress-bar

This is my scenario. 
I have a promotion that ends at a particular time. Only if the number of entries reaches a particular threshold will the promotion take place. 
So to users I have to show progress of 2 events, 
1) Time to completion
2) How many more users need to participate for the promotion to take place.

How do I show this information in ios, Android mobile platforms?

A promotion is going to be a card view. There might be multiple promotions happening at the same time and in the screen we show multiple card views at the moment.

Comment: If you're satisfied with the answer by Mike M , please mark it as Accepted

Answer (score 3):

Would something like Kickstarter work?

Similar to your situation, they have to tell users:

- how close to funding they are (a function of money; users can be 1 to n)
- when the window for funding ends (the project has a fixed window to get the funding)

Where it differs is that it sounds like you need to show the minimum # of users needed; a graphic treatment could call attention when you're close to the required number ('Only 2 more needed!').

Kickstarter in mobile has a simple progress bar for funding, and a number to indicate days; you could even do a countdown hours clock when it gets below a day.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Although you say "*I have to show **progress** of 2 events*", I think the key to representing this is realising that one of these measures is "*progress*" (the number of users) and the other is a diminishing "*resource*" (time left). You could then potentially combine both measures in a single component:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyQKCl.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

- The *shading* of the left-hand portion increases to show how close to the minimum number of users you have got (potentially changing colour from red to orange/yellow as it gets closer to the minimum). Once the minimum is reached, I don't think you need to *graphically* show by how much it has been exceeded (you'd just show it at 100% full, possibly in green) but you could continue to reflect the total count in the legend below.
- The *width* of the right-hand portion will decrease to represent the time remaining in which to attract users (again possibly turning from a neutral colour to orange/red as time runs out (assuming the minimum count hasn't already been reached).